# MongoDb: Select a random record with a specifi condition and update it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Friends

I have a collection with around 20 records of lastAccessed as null and now I want to select a random lastAccessed and update it with $$Now for which I have the below code

```js
    db.myCollection.aggregate([
      { $match: { lastAccessed: { $exists: False}  }},
      { $sample:{ size: 1 }}
    ]);
    db.myCollection.updateOne(
      { _id: 1 },
      {
        $set: {
            tableName: 'myTable',
            lastAccessed: '$$NOW'
        }
      })
```

**My question is how do I know the id of the randomly selected record to update it correctly ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you can use `$merge` at the end of the aggregation pipeline to perform update by id behaviour.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "lastAccessed": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tableName: "myTable",
      lastAccessed: "$$NOW"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
]).forEach( function(myDoc) { print( "tableName: " + myDoc.tableName ); } );
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WZF8cox9olX) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you is there a way to return only Table Name of the modified record ?

Comment: @ronan not sure if I am understanding correctly, as you are updating `tableName` to "myTable", your expected return is always "myTable"?

Comment: the output is 
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "lastAccessed": ISODate("2022-02-16T14:11:56.686Z"),
    "tableName": "myTable"
  }
]
However I need only myTable as a string output then how to achieve ?

Comment: @ronan [forEach cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#example) could be what you are looking for when you want to manipulate the aggregation output

Comment: could you please show me how it can be used in above case ?

Comment: @ronan updated the answer to demo the usage of forEach

Comment: Thank you , Im getting below error 
Invalid query:
Line 27: Expected 'i' instead of 'o'

Comment: @ronan please raise a new question instead of extending discussions in comment in order to keeping the original question as focused as it is as of now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't want to use aggregate,

To get Updated Document, can use [findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { lastAccessed: { $exists: false } },
    { $set: { lastAccessed: "$$NOW" } },
    { returnOriginal: false }
)
```

Use { returnOriginal: true | false } option for Mongodb 3.6 earlier version,

For MongoDb 3.6 and after 3.6 Version, can use { returnDocument: "after", "before" },

{ new: true | false } option for mongoose

Comment: Thank you is there a way to return only Table Name of the modified record ?